# Run GitLab job only if variable is provided

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I have two jobs in my gitlab ci pipeline 'job a' and 'job b'. I want only 'job a' to run if variable x is provided and run 'job b' if variable b isn't provided.
Something like this.

```
job a:
  rule:
    - if: variable X is provided
  script:
    - do something

job b:
  rule:
    - if: variable X is not provided
  script:
    - do something
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with considering an empty variable value equivalent to it not being "provided", you can do this:

```yaml
if: $x == ''
```

for "not provided" and

```yaml
if: $x != ''
```

for "provided".